# How to loop over a command returned value in a batch

Tags: batch-file, tfs

I'm write a batch script to do some TFS operation in my CI server.

```
tf.exe" workspaces /collection:http://hostname:8080/tfs/Collection /login:DOMAIN\Service,Password
```

The above command returns all the workspaces in the collection:

```
Workspace               Owner        Computer  Comment
----------------------- ------------ --------- ---------
WorkspaceA              Owner1       Computer1
WorkspaceB              Owner2       Computer1
```

Is it possible to loop over the result and delete workspce WorkspaceA and WorkspaceB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not tested:

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,3 delims= " %%A in (
   'tf.exe" workspaces /collection:http://hostname:8080/tfs/Collection /login:DOMAIN\Service,Password'
) do (
   echo %%A %%B
)
```